# How do I derive the michaelis menten equation (part 1)?

Tags: proof-explanation

My textbook in chemistry ("Biochemistry", Stryer et. al 9th ed p. 246) states that:

$$[ES]=\frac{[E][S]}{K_m}$$

where [ES] is the concentration of the enzyme-substrate-complex, [E] is the concentration of enzyme and [S] is the concentration of substrate. For the purposes of this discussion, we'll just regard $K_m$ as a constant I think.

The book then claims that:

$$[E]=[E]_T-[ES]$$

Substituting this into the first expression yields:

$$[ES]=\frac{([E]_T-[ES])[S]}{K_m}$$

And that I can live with. In the next step however, "Solving [the last equation] for [ES]" is supposed to give:

$$[ES]=\frac{\frac{[E_T][S]}{K_m}}{\frac{1+[S]}{K_m}}$$

How exactly do we arrive at that step?

Comment: Aren't you missing some "=" signs here and there?

Comment: That's true, sorry 'bout that

Comment: I guess by $K_M$ you mean $K_m$.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware I was being inconsistent, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last expression is not entirely correct. Nevertheless, this is an elementary school problem: $$
\left[ {ES} \right] = \frac{{(\left[ E \right]_T  - \left[ {ES} \right])\left[ S \right]}}{{K_m }} = \frac{{\left[ E \right]_T \left[ S \right]}}{{K_m }} - \frac{{\left[ {ES} \right]\left[ S \right]}}{{K_m }} \\\Rightarrow \left[ {ES} \right] + \frac{{\left[ {ES} \right]\left[ S \right]}}{{K_m }} = \frac{{\left[ E \right]_T \left[ S \right]}}{{K_m }} \Rightarrow \left[ {ES} \right]\left( {1 + \frac{{\left[ S \right]}}{{K_m }}} \right) = \frac{{\left[ E \right]_T \left[ S \right]}}{{K_m }} \Rightarrow \left[ {ES} \right] = \frac{{\frac{{\left[ E \right]_T \left[ S \right]}}{{K_m }}}}{{1 + \frac{{\left[ S \right]}}{{K_m }}}},
$$
or
$$
\left[ {ES} \right] = \frac{{\left[ E \right]_T \left[ S \right]}}{{K_m  + \left[ S \right]}}.
$$